# Group-owned GitLab CI Runner not being assigned any jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My organization has two GitLab CI runners spun up on DigitalOcean. These runners have the exact same system configuration, Docker servers on Ubuntu.

The only difference between these two servers is how they are assigned to the GitLab (gitlab.com) projects:

- Runner 1 is assigned on a project-by-project basis
- Runner 2 is assigned to the top-level group owning all projects

Visual for clarity:

```
+ Group
|
+--- Runner 2
|
|--+ Sub-Group 1
|  |
|  +--+ Project 1.1
|  |  |
|  |  +--- Runner 1
|  |
|  +--+ Project 1.2
|     |
|     +--- Runner 1
|
+--+ Sub-Group 2
   |
   +--+ Project 2.1
   |  |
   |  +--- Runner 1
   |
   +--+ Project 2.2
      |
      +--- Runner 1
```

The only runner actually picking up jobs is Runner 1. Runner 2 appears as an "Available Group Runner" in the CI/CD settings for all projects, but not their second-level subgroups.

Is there a better way to do this? We'd rather avoid having to assign the runners on a per-project basis, but the group runner functionality is not working for us with the current configuration.

Our ideal configuration:

```
+ Group
|
+--- Runner 2
|
|--+ Sub-Group 1
|  |
|  +--- Runner 1
|  |
|  +--+ Project 1.1
|  |
|  +--+ Project 1.2
|
+--+ Sub-Group 2
   |
   +--+ Project 2.1
   |
   +--+ Project 2.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge and research, GitLab does not support this functionality. GitLab Group Runners appear to only be available to projects directly within the scope of the group in question and not to any subgroups.

Hopefully this functionality is addressed in the future. Until then, I will continue to add Runners on a per-repo basis.